# Log-scaled chart for visualizing extreme range

Tags: data-visualization, scales, logarithm

I need a simple bar chart or the like. I am not a statistician by any means, but this chart is supposed to accurately represent FileIO in MB/s compared to the theoretical peak of a specific drive.

The first value is always 30,000.
The second value is variable, but leans towards the extremely low 1–10 thousand-ish area.

Can anybody recommend how to scale this the best way so that you can see changes in lower values and that they're really far from the peak?

Comment: Are there only 2 values, or is there a series of values like the 2nd one or in between the two?

Comment: there are thousands of values, one for each program run., but when a user is logged in, they will see a list of programs they've run, and when they choose one, this chart will load with 2 values only (the first is 30,000, and the second is a variable value trending towards the low end) @xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30:1 scale is not too much for a normal linear scale of two values. (If you had lots of small values, it would worth doing something special to see how they vary amongst themselves.) With a log or other transformation you lose any benefit of an intuitive understanding of the comparison.

Showing just two values at a time where one sounds like a theoretical maximum value, you might try overlaid bars to give the impression of a proportion.

[image]

Is the high value is more of a benchmark instead of a maximum, you can use a bullet style bar chart.

[image]

With a [bullet graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph), you have options to show multiple benchmark values using shading, such as if 10,000 is "good" and 30,000 is "max". Example from Wikipedia:

[image]